# How to do a PUT (partial update) using generics in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I have a class view that looks like this,

```
class MovieDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

how do I make the serialize accept partial updates? currently where it stands Put will erase an existing data for said object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the DRF route, use `PATCH` method instead of `PUT`.

if you write the urls configuration by yourself,
dispatch it to `partial_update` method in your `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` view.

If you get the serialize by yourself, 
pass the `partial=True` to your Serializer

```
partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just overwrite the get_serializer() method as:

```
  def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return super(MovieDetail, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is especially useful when the front-end guy use the ngResource of the AngularJS to call your API, which only supports the 'put' instead of the 'patch' by default.

Hope it helps.