# PUT requests with DjangoRestFramework

Tags: http, django-rest-framework, put

I am building a rest API and am wondering both about HTTP best practices I guess, and how that would apply to the DRF. When sending a PUT request, in the body, do requests have all of the parameters for objects that they would be manipulating? Even if not all of them are changing? Or do they only send the fields that are being updated? So for example if we had a `House` object with `No. of rooms` and `floors`, and I was changing `No. of rooms` should I only send that parameter, or both of them?

If requests should only contain the fields that are being updating, then how would that translate to the DjangoRestFramework? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Views are:

```
 class HouseDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     queryset = House.objects.all()
     serializer_class = HouseSerializer
```

and serializer is:

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quotes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'address',
            'quotes',
        )
```

Comment: you can check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761322/how-to-do-a-put-partial-update-using-generics-in-django-rest-framework/29761525#29761525), it's duplicated one I think..

Answer (score 1):

`PUT` is for full resource updates, `PATCH` is for partial resource updates [because Fielding says so](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/275471320685367296).

Therefore, in your example, if you wanted to only update a `No. of rooms` for your `HouseDetail` model, you would send the following payload in a `PATCH` request:

```
{ "no. of rooms": "42" }
```

It is still possible to partially update things with a `PUT` request  in `DRF` (explained below) but you should simply use `PATCH` for that because it was created for this. You get `PUT` and `PATCH` functionality for your model because you have subclassed the `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` class and have defined a serializer.

If a required field is omitted in your `PUT` request (see [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/) for `required`), then you will receive a `400` status code with a response like `{"detail": "x field is required"}`. However, when you request via `PATCH`, there is a `partial=True` argument passed to the serializer which allows this partial only update. We can see this for the `UpdateModelMixin`:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

which calls update, which is:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```