# Django/REST: Support partial updates during object-level validation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Lets say, I have a serializer that performs object-level validation:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'feathers')

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['type'] != 'bird' and data['feathers'] != null:
            raise ValidationError({'feathers': 'Only supported by birds!'})
        return data
```

What's the best way to support partial updates, i.e. REST requests with `patch` method?

My naive approach would be to do it by hand:

```
    def validate(self, data):
        data['type'] = data.get('type') or self.instance.type
        data['feathers'] = data.get('feathers') or self.instance.feathers
        if data['type'] != 'bird' and data['feathers'] != null:
            raise ValidationError({'feathers': 'Only supported by birds!'})
        return data
```

But I think this is quite messy and error-prone. Are there any more elegant solutions?

---

**Update:** Looks like this needs some clarification. I'm asking for a good practice to *support* partial updates *during object-level validation*, i.e. within the `validate` method. I'm *not asking* about how to *do* that partial updates. I *know* that!

Comment: I just use the patch method

Comment: @ChrisHawkes what do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761322/how-to-do-a-put-partial-update-using-generics-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I don't see how this should fix the object-level validation problem.